# Trying to Add Resource in Visual Studio 2010 Pro SP1 results in "The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error" message with C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resources, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Windows XP Professional SP3 and recently switched to Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1 to work on a C++ project.

If I try to right-click on a project inside Solution Explorer and select "Add" >> "Resource...", I get this error popup window:

"The operation could not be completed.  Unspecified error"

And then the only option is to click "OK".

Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Did you have one of the Visual Studio 2010 Beta versions installed?

Comment: I narrowed the problem a little bit more:  Since VS2010SP1 is excruciatingly slow with C++ IntelliSense (keeps updating some sort of DB that makes builds take 3x the time and general responsiveness to be much slower), I had disabled the Code Browsing Info DB - which makes it run as fast as VS2008 did used to be.  But I lose all IntelliSense.  If I reenable the Code Browsing Info DB I no longer get the "Unspecified error".  I get a bit further but I get another prompt that hangs:  "Please wait while "Resource Script Wizard" prepares to start.  Click Cancel to end "Resource Script Wizard".

Comment: No - I had never installed any Betas of VS2010.  But I have both VS2010Express and VS2010Pro (SP1) installed.  I installed VS2010Express first, then VS2010Pro (SP1).  Not sure if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer regarding to this problem on **[Visual Studio Hosting Process and “The operation could not be completed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338/visual-studio-hosting-process-and-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/50497064#50497064)**.

Comment: Wow it's been 6.5 years since I've posted this question...  :)  Unfortunately I have no way to verify, I've switched jobs a long time ago...

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem.

Right clicking on the project, selecting *Unload Project*, then right clicking again and clicking *Reload Project* fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure of the exact reason for this, but it had something to do with the Code Browsing Info DB that I had disabled to speed up VS2010.  Seems VS won't allow entering the Add Resource wizard if the Code Browsing Info DB is disabled.

Still with the DB re-enabled I got the hanging "Please wait while 'Resource Script Wizard' prepares to start. Click Cancel to end 'Resource Script Wizard'" prompt.  Not sure how it finally disappeared, but I had to do a reboot and did close my Outlook mail client after the reboot while doing a couple more trials.  Not sure if it has anything to do, but after that I was able to enter the Add Resource Wizard.

Maybe the good old Microsoft-style troubleshooting reboots still works after all these years.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was cause by Google Recaptcha control.

I'd generate ressource after my page was completed so he catch my recaptcha Control but added a weird tag in his XML document.

Here is what I propose to you, open your resources file using XML editor and check out if there is not a weird tags which is widely different than other one. Maybe for me it's recatpcha, but maybe for you it's another third party.

Check out mine what it looks like :

```
<!-- OTHER TAGS --->
<data name="aControlResource1.ToolTip" xml:space="preserve">
  <value />
</data>
<!-- 
     THIS IS THE NASTY TAGS ... REMOVING IT MAKE IT WORKS PERFECTLY.
-->
<assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<data name="recaptchaResource1.ErrorMessage" type="System.Resources.ResXNullRef, System.Windows.Forms">
   <value />
</data>
<data name="anotherControlResource1.ToolTip" xml:space="preserve">
  <value />
</data>
<!-- OTHER TAGS -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i had same problem, the solution its simple, you should close resource file then u can insert another image resource, Visual Studio cant add ids to bitmap while the file steel open **"resource.h"**