# VS2008 WinForm project, error occured when run the project : 'The operation could not be completed. The process cannot access the file'

Tags: c#, winforms, bug-tracking

I have a winforms application in VS2008 FrameWork 3.5. When I Run the application in debug mode, error occures:
'The operation could not be completed. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

then after i close the Visual studio editor and go to applications foler/bin/debug, and delete the abc.vshost.exe file and then start project, project then run successfully.

I want to know why this error occures, and how to fix it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug and probably not a lot you can do about it aside from restarting VS. You can try a Clean, but I suspect it will also not work.

Comment: yeh, i have tried it allready..

Comment: You might have a look at my answer regarding to this problem on **[Visual Studio Hosting Process and “The operation could not be completed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338/visual-studio-hosting-process-and-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/50497064#50497064)**.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the vshost.exe file is occupied by other process. You can use Process Explorer to find which process is using this file. 
For detail about how to use it to find the file handle, please refer to: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm

The vshost.exe file is a stub file for VS debugger. Visual Studio will start  vshost.exe process instead your exe file when debugging. It may happens that the vshost.exe file doesn't correct stopped when you stop debugging. You may also use Process Explorer to find if there is any process is named as MyProg.vshost.exe.

-- Taken from MDSN forum

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/csharp-fails-start-visual-studio-2008-26572.aspx

Comment: Process Explorer is nice software but it is not helping to solve this problem. I read whole forum, but till end of this i didn't find the solution for it. 
thnx for reply.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a rather common problem with a lot of possible causes and solutions. I had this issue with VS2010 when using wildcards in the assembly version number, e.g. "1.0.*".

I used the first workaround from this source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533411/visual-studio-keeps-locking-files

Removing the wildcard worked for me.

Comment: but i am not using wildcard, i have read this forum, but did'nt get any solution.

Comment: As I wrote, there are many possible causes that lead to this behaviour. I remember that I did hours of searching until I found "my" solution. Another shot: did you try to disable the VS hosting process?

Comment: what is VS hosting process and how can i disbale it.

Comment: I am suffering this problem from last 14 months, and many times i tried to resolve this, but till now i did'nt find any solution.

Comment: VS hosting process: open the project properties. On the "Debug"-Tab there should be a checkmark "Enable Visual Studio hosting process". Remoce this.