# The operation could not be completed access is denied while opening microsoft visual studio application

Tags: asp.net

I have formated the comp and installed windows 7 enterprise edition. Now my visual studio 2005 application while opening from solution explorer source code will be displayed but when i click to design it will shows error as " the operation could not be completed access is denied "

Please help me

thanx in advance
shubha

Comment: right click on VS exe > run as > administrator might help

Comment: You might have a look at my answer regarding to this problem on **[Visual Studio Hosting Process and “The operation could not be completed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338/visual-studio-hosting-process-and-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/50497064#50497064)**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an access rights issue due to the new installation, check all your project folders and their subfolders for the given rights.