# The Operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I created a C# Website using Visual studio 2015 in my laptop, i copied the same folder to my desktop system and open in Visual studio 2015, when i try to run the application its suddenly gives following error.

> **The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the path specified**

Anybody feel same error in your latest Visual Studio 2015? I updated all the latest patches.

following trial are done

- Re created the soluition file(.sln)
- Deleted Web.config and added new one

[image: Visual studio 2015 Error The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the path specified]

Still the error exists, so i cant able to debug or run the application.

Comment: Do you have the same environment components installed on both systems? I mean .net version, iis, any libraries you use in your project. Also, maybe you have set some custom paths in project (project startup path, browser)?

Comment: Yes, both system having Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition,  I updated both system with latest patches from Microsoft. Framework 4.5.2 in both system

Comment: can you show us the files present in your M*** Web folder.?.You can do this by right clicking on solution->Open in folder.I would like to know what are the files your folder contains in order to open the project.

Comment: following are the contents as you mentioned
1. one fade foldercalled .vs
2. App_Code
3. All my aspx and .cs files
4. Web.Config
and other css, js and fonts folders

Comment: what about .sln file?which helps in linking all files into a single solution file.How did you open this project?

Comment: Yes .sln file also there

Comment: Remove the solution from VS if you have saved it,then re-start the system and open the folder of the solution,double click on .sln ,it must load all the files accordingly.Now try to build it.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above steps, but the error still sexists :(

Comment: It can be a PATH length limit, visual studio supports a max of 259 chars in path. Try to copy solution in C: folder.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer regarding to this problem on **[Visual Studio Hosting Process and “The operation could not be completed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338/visual-studio-hosting-process-and-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/50497064#50497064)**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(1) Run VS as an admin (or elevated access) and open the solution. 
(2) Set up a project as Start up Project (if you have multiple proj) 
(3) Set up page as start up page.

this should help you run it

Comment: This solved for me after I copied a web project from a colleague. After the first run as administrator I could open and run normally as well. My guess is this is to do with the IIS Express that needed to set up on a different port

Answer (score 9):

Create manually (Windows Explorer if necessary) a folder with name "Service References". Even if the folder does not appear in the Solution Explorer, is there.
Try adding the wsdl (xml) file again.

Comment: It seems that VS2019 (in my case) sometimes doesn't add the folder automatically, creating the folder manually solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, resolved by creating a Connected Services folder in my project.

So juste create a Connected Services folder or a Service References folder in your project

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error. When I shorten the file path of the solution, the error disappear. I think you may put your solution to a folder with too long path name or your solution have some file with too long name.

Answer (score 0):

I got a more specific project-load error message when I removed the project from the solution and tried to re-add it. In my case, it was because the URL/address of the application had changed in my local IIS. When I updated the  tag in the .vbproj (or .csproj) file to the new value, then the project loaded successfully.