# Add WCF via 'Add Connected Services' using VS2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2019

**Hello everyone,**

I tried to add WCF service to the Asp.net MVC project as Connected Services, but every time I got this error message "The system cannot find the path specified"

Please give me any tips, suggestions or solutions on this subject and thanks

**UW Thank you (;**

[image: Error Message]

[image: No WCF service]

Comment: In my opinion, this is likely to be caused by a connection string error, you need to check your connection string.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT , Thank you for the answer, but there is no type of connection string,  I need any information that might help me to solve this problem

Comment: @MahmodAbuJehad I'm not sure what you are doing after selecting connected services, please explain in order to help. P.S. I usually select 'Add Service Reference' while connecting WCF Services. Not sure if it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem that I found the answer to in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343513/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified) following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65906491/7535354)

So just create a `Connected Services` folder or a `Service References` folder in your project.

Comment: Hello, that means the question is a duplicate isn't it?